# Disk space usage when shrinking disk in VMware Workstation

Tags: vmware-workstation

Does VMware Workstation require additional temporary disk space when shrinking a disk (for say a temporary shrunk VMDK file) or does it shrink the existing VMDK file in place?

Comment: It needs temporary storage

Comment: You are correct. Using the -k (shrink) option with vmware-vdiskmanager.exe does indeed create a temporary file (can watch it in resource monitor). So does the defragment option. However, if you use the "Compact" option in VMware Workstation itself, it appears to work directly on the VMDK file. Watching a compact now and it's reading & writing to the same VMDK file

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a "compact" option with the command line tool. The reason I asked this question is that I'm trying to using the compact option in VMware v12 on a large VMDK file but it keeps crashing. I thought I'd try the command line utility to see if it gave any more information as to why compact was crashing. But kind of stuck if there isn't the same option with the command line tool

Comment: compact and shrink are two different functions.  One shrinks the size of the disk partition, the other reduces the size based on free space on the partition, they are used for two entirely different reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command line utility using the -k option copies the used sectors in a VMDK into a temporary file, deletes the original and renames the temporary copy. Therefore when using -k option you need to have as much free disk space needed for the new shrunk VMDK.

The compact option in the user interface (edit VM properties) compacts the disk in place, i.e. it moves all used sectors into free sectors nearer the logical start of the VMDK and then resizes the size of the file. Therefore you don't need any free disk space for this option.